# converting to upper and lower case in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++builder

I wrote this code in c++

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

    char convert1 (char x[])
    {
    for ( int i =0; i<5;i++)
    {
    if ( i/2 ==0 )
    x[i] =tolower(x[i]);
    else
    x[i] = toupper(x[i]);

    return x[i];

}
    }

   int main()
   {
      char z[] = "REDCA";
      cout<<convert1(z); 
      return 0;
   }
```

it will work but it always print only the small case of the first letter R. but I want to print the complete word like this 
rEdCa

so how can i modify it please

Comment: possible duplicate of [write a function in C++ to convert string to upper and lower case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802305/write-a-function-in-c-to-convert-string-to-upper-and-lower-case)

Answer (score 3):

You want `if(i%2 == 0)` rather than `if(i/2 == 0)` (probably a typo).

Also, you are only returning `x[i]`, which is a single `char`. The better idea would be using `std::string` instead of `char *`, but you can make this work with `char *` as well. (I won't provide full code, as we have established in your previous question, this is your assignment and you should do it, not us.)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `convert1` is `char`. So, `cout << convert1(x)` sees a `char`, and thus you just get the first `r`.

You probably want something like this:

```
template<size_t S>
char const* convert1(char (&x)[S])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < S; ++i)
    {
        if(i%2 ==0) {
            x[i] = tolower(x[i]);
        } else {
            x[i] = toupper(x[i]);
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

Want better, use a `std::string`.

Comment: @Ahmed Your assignment, your job. Using this site to get full solutions for homework is cheating.

Comment: @AhmedYaisn Please don't ask homework questions, leaves me with a bad taste in my mouth when I solve it for you.

Comment: @sehe Didn't realise it was a homework problem until I had. Ah well, got to exercise my new found (and never to be used again) template to pass an array skills.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain `bool cheers(T (&cya)[N]) { return N>0; }` :)